# Pass a parameter from one jsp to another using form.action

Tags: jsp, parameters

I have an ID that I need in the next jsp once the user click a button.  I am trying to do the following:

FirstJSP.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSecond() {
        var frm = document.getElementById("frm");
        frm.action = "**second.jsp?id=myId;"**
        frm.submit();
    }
</script>
...
form id="frm"
      .....
            input type="button" value="Next" onclick="getSecond()"/

 ......
```

This code takes me to my second page, but if I tried to access the id, it gives me an error since the id is null.

I access the id in the second page by:

```
final Long passedId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
```

I think I am not passing the parameter correctly, but I don't know how to do it.   Any ideas?  Thank you so much!

Comment: You didn't specify, but I'm assuming your form's action is POST.  Sounds like you are mixing GET style params (ie. ?id=myId) with POST.  Dunno if that works, would have to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... I found my mistake... I wans't using any method in my form, so I updated it to

```
form name="frm" method="post"
```

Also, like I mentioned in my last note, the action line is now

```
frm.action="second.jsp?id="+<%=myId%>;
```

It works now!

Comment: You figured it out before I could reply to your reply? Cool. Then I can stop thinking about it and resume my nap.

Comment: By the way, if the HTML form element doesn't have any 'method' attribute specified, then it will default to "GET". In such case, you would need to implement Servlet's doGet() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the code fragment you give above is literally what you are writing, then you are setting id to the text "myId". When you try to parse this as a Long it throws an exception because the string is not a valid number -- it doesn't contain any digits.

I presume what you want to say is something more like

frm.action="second.jsp?id="+myId

Assuming that myId has been defined somewhere and is a number.

Comment: You are right Jay.  But if I tried just adding myId, the variable is "unresolved variable or Type".   myId is defined at the beginning as <% final Long myId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id")); %>

I have changed the action line to 
frm.action="second.jsp?id="+<%=myId%>;   and still doen't work